# How to speed up browsing in Selenium/Firefox?

Tags: selenium

I am using python to automate selenium/firefox. The code I have will load about 85,000 different webpages. I understand that this will take a long time but if it can be done I wouldn't mind it going faster than it currently is..Right now one webpage load can range from 5 to 10 seconds. I know it could be the website and/or my internet connection but I was wondering if there was a way that I could just load stuff that is important so that it will go faster. I have seen this before in browsers..not loading images and javascript, etc. I would like to know if this is possible for firefox in selenium. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable images/css/javascript but afaik its an all or nothing switch and you may need some of these to make your app work.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.stylesheet", 2);
profile.setPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
profile.setPreference("javascript.enabled", false);
FirefoxDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

The above would allow you to disable these.

One thing that might be easier that i recommend is to run selenium in a headless browser like htmlunit or phantomjs, these should run your tests much faster also.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried what my app does manually in chrome with things disabled and I think it will work. I'll give it a try.

Comment: I'll think about the headless browser. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this in python...do you know?

Comment: oh I think I found it. sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need any content like pictures, javascript, etc., then you should probably be using something like BeautifulSoup

```
pip install bs4
```

.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

soup = BeautifulSoup( urllib2.urlopen( "http://google.com" ).read(), "html5lib" )

soup.select( "body > div" )
```

Comment: Not necessarily, many sites include security features which won't allow headless responses.